# Where are recentf entries stored? How can I import them into another emacs installation?

Tags: recentf

I've installed emacs on a new OS, and would like to maintain my 'recentf' file history entries (they'll be in the same location thanks to symlinks).

Where are these entries stored? And how could I export + improt them to the new emacs installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine where the recentf file is, you can query the variable `recentf-save-file`. By default, that is `~/.emacs.d/recentf`. In spacemacs that is `~/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf`.

You can copy this file over to the new machine, or you can open the file and copy the entries. AFAIK there is no functionality to import/export, as that's a very exclusive use case and often doesn't make much sense across machines.

Comment: Sadly this no longer seems to work. Seems to get overridden by an empty file when attempting this.