# Add recent files to .viminfo

Tags: spacemacs, evil, recentf, vim-emulation

Is there a package or code snippet that can make Emacs add recent files to .viminfo? I want this to use with `v`. (Basically to open recent files using `fzf`)

I’m using Spacemacs (so evil, too), if that matters.

Ps: Where does `recentf` save its data?

Comment: As answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46232/where-are-recentf-entries-stored-how-can-i-import-them-into-another-emacs-insta/46233#46233), recentf stores data in whatever file you define by setting the variable `recentf-save-file`.